# Logging in to target.com with script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to the world of programming so I am trying to make a simple login script that will log me in to target.com when ran! Eventually I will want to add other things to it but I can’t seem to figure out the best way to do this. Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using a tool like Puppeteer or Selenium can be used to automate browser tasks.

The basic idea is to use the tool to navigate to the website url, then while on the page you have to get references to the DOM elements you want to interact with. Once you do that you can use the tool to simulate events like clicking, typing etc.

However, logging in to sites like Target using scripts poses issues because they have ways to guard against automated scripts accessing their site. Some defenses include setting up Captchas and examining request headers.

Comment: They don’t have recaptcha so I don’t think it should be that hard. I am trying to do it all request based if possible.

Comment: Sometimes the recaptchas are only visible when you do something that triggers them, like a script would

Comment: I need my program to be fast though and i don’t think selenium or puppeteer will be fast enough in the long run. The end goal of this will be the script will login and then monitor a product until I stock and checkout. So 3 steps